# How to save a VBA nested dictionary to excel cells?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

Not sure how to save a nested dictionary created with Visual Basic Applications to an excel spreadsheet. Would it be best to loop and save or use Application.Transpose(dic.Keys)?  If we use Transpose, how can we save the inner keys as well?

```
Sub GenerateCatalogList()

Dim dictA As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim dictB As New Scripting.Dictionary

dictB.Add "Catalog", "XXX DJSQVOS"
dictB.Add "Qty", 1

dictA.Add "Item_1", dictB

' Save Transposed dictionary here?
Range("G3").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dictB.Items)

Dim outerKey As Variant
Dim innerKey As Variant

For Each outerKey In dictA.Keys
    Debug.Print "Main key: "; outerKey
    Debug.Print "inner key: "
    For Each innerKey In dictA(outerKey)
        Debug.Print innerKey; ": "; dictA(outerKey)(innerKey)
        
        ' save dictionary here?
        Range("F3").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dictA(outerKey)(innerKey))
        
        
    Next innerKey
    Debug.Print "---------------"
Next outerKey

        
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel talks VBA. You don't need to "save" anything. Maybe you meant **display** the dictionary?

Comment: @StureS I'm trying to save the keys and items of the inner dictionary to multiple cells.  Eventually there will be lots of catalogs and Qty and I want to generate a list that users can copy and paste

Comment: I think I need to do something like this "Range("E3").Resize(1, _
             UBound(Application.Transpose(dictB.Items))) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dictB.Items)" but it just keeps writing the same item

Comment: Then you debug your code. Set a breakpoint and single step from there. Examine variables and their values. That's what troubleshooting is all about.

Comment: Assuming your dictionary items are simple numbers and strings, serialize to JSON, save as text? Unserialize back etc https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you sure you need nested dictionaries ?

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GenerateCatalogList()
    Dim dictA As New Scripting.Dictionary, key, cell As Range
    
    dictA.Add "Item_1", Array("XXX DJSQVOS", 1)
    dictA.Add "Item_2", Array("AAA DJSQVOS", 2)
    dictA.Add "Item_3", Array("BBB DJSQVOS", 3)
    dictA.Add "Item_4", Array("CCC DJSQVOS", 4)
    
    Range("F2:H2") = Array("Item", "Catalog", "Qu")
    Set cell = Range("F3")
    For Each key In dictA.Keys
        cell = key
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2) = dictA(key)
        Set cell = cell.Offset(1)
    Next
End Sub
```